# Elsevier cas-sc document class: cannot print citation call-outs bounded by square brackets

Tags: citing, natbib, els-cas

cas-sc class and bibliographystyle {elsarticle-num}. when i run this i get citation call-outs bounded by ( ) instead of [ ].

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

Citation call-outs i get are `(1)` `(2)` `(3)` instead of `[1]` `[2]` `[3]`

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{mybib}
```

Comment: Off-topic: The `subfigure` package has been deprecated for more than a decade. Don't load it. Instead, use the machinery of the `subcaption` package. Incidentally, the `subfigure` and `subcaption` packages are mutually incompatible -- another reason for loading just the `subcaption` package.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked.

Comment: @Marijn - I dont think it's a clean dupe. The earlier posting claimed they had already solved the appearance of the citation call-outs.

Comment: @Mico you are right that the other question asked something different. However, since it was very similar and the answer was the same I voted as a duplicate. In the end closing questions is about helping people to solve their problem and preventing the same information in multiple places, I think that goal is served with this closure.

Answer (score 2):

You should change `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc}

% create a sample bib file "on the fly":
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a,author="Anne Author",    title="U", year=3001}
@misc{b,author="Brenda Branson", title="V", year=3002}
@misc{c,author="Carla Carlucci", title="W", year=3003}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{subfigure} % <-- don't load this package, it's deprecated
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite{a}, \cite{b}, \cite{c}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```